# Dynamic calculation of the number of groups members

Tags: alfresco, activiti

For example, there are one `exclusivegateway` and two `sequenceFlow`.

```
<sequenceFlow id="flow1" sourceRef="exclusivegateway" targetRef="usertask1">
    <conditionExpression xsi:type="tFormalExpression">
        <![CDATA[${approveCount == N}]]>
    </conditionExpression>
</sequenceFlow>

<sequenceFlow id="flow2" sourceRef="exclusivegateway" targetRef="usertask2">
    <conditionExpression xsi:type="tFormalExpression">
        <![CDATA[${approveCount < N}]]>
    </conditionExpression>
</sequenceFlow>
```

Depending on conditions, executed one or the other task.

In business process I want to dynamically calculate the number `N`. This number is equal to the sum of all participants of the business process. 
(for example, I have two groups and the first group included `10` participants, the second group included `5`. Then `N` must be equal to `15`).

Is it possible in Activiti by using JavaScript to calculate the number of participants in these groups?

Comment: yes you can do mathematical operation in javascript.
or you can use script task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could definitely use either JavaScript or Java API for getting the the number of users in a couple of groups. Check this page for JS people API for example: http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/references/API-JS-getMembers.html

So I imagine a Script task/execution listener before your exclusive gateway, implementing that logic should be the easiest way to do this, as it won't even require restarting the server:

```
var membersG1 = people.getMembers("GROUP_MY_GROUP1_NAME");
var membersG2 = people.getMembers("GROUP_MY_GROUP2_NAME");
execution.setVariable("N", membersG1.length + membersG2.length);
```

Note that this is one of many many possible ways for implementing what you specified.